# Can the CI_JOB_TOKEN with GitLab be used to push to the repo and create a tag?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to push to a GitLab repo with the automatically provided CI_JOB_TOKEN. Is this currently permitted or do I have to create a tag explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/#creating-a-deploy-token). Then in your script use that access token as follows.

`git push http://$CI_USER:$CI_ACCESS_TOKEN@$GIT_REMOTE.git $BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: Sure, but requires manual work.

Comment: That's correct. If you already using private token for rest API, you could leverage deploy keys API. But it still involves some manual work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to create a tag, you can do this without any additional token setup using the [`release:` feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release) (or the [releases API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/) which accepts job tokens).

The most basic example:

```yaml
myjob:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - echo "creating release"
  release:
    tag_name: "v1.0.0"    
    name: 'v1.0.0'
    description: 'Release created using the release-cli.'
```

And this will create a release and push the git tag without needing any additional tokens.

A common pattern I use is to dynamically determine the tag/release name (version) then pass that variable along using `artifacts:reports:dotenv` to a job that creates the tag and release.

```yaml
set_tag_variable:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - TAG_NAME="$(get-next-semver.sh)"
    - echo "TAG_NAME=${TAG_NAME}" > tag.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: tag.env


add_tag:
  needs: [set_tag_variable]
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  script:
    - echo "Creating the release."
  release:
    tag_name: $TAG_NAME
    name: 'Release $TAG_NAME'
    description: 'Release created using the release-cli.'
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, it is not possible to use the job token. But there is an open [issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/6310) about it.